# Seeing basemap created by Oracle map builder in database

Tags: oracle-spatial

I am new in oracle, I tried to create a style, then different themes and then a base map. I saved all my work, but I can't see the base map in the database.

Did I miss something?

The interesting part is that I have a spatial table, which has a geometry field, but I can't see that in Map Builder.

Answer (score 2):

Basemap definitions are stored in table (actually a view) USER_SDO_MAPS. Style and theme definitions are in USER_SDO_STYLES and USER_SDO_THEMES.

To view the content of a spatial table (graphically) you need to expand the "Show Data" button at the bottom left of the Mapbuilder window. Just right-click the table whose content you want to view, and select "Preview". On the map window you are shown, click the green arrow button to start the actual preview.